# Where are MAAS images stored?

Tags: maas

Hi I'm trying to import the Wily image but doing so over a really shoty network. It's easier for me to download manually and keep trying then waiting for MAAS to finish or magically work.

Or is there a way to monitor the download of the image from MAAS from the front end it seems stuck at 15%.

P.S: I wish MAAS had better monitoring of tasks. It's almost impossible to tell what is working and isn't working when deploying stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I found this...

https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/sstreams-mirror.html

Hopefully it will help speed up the process! :)